# Text animation using java-script and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to create an animation which after my click on an article will increase text opacity from 0.2 to 1. I used property hover in CSS, but It wasn't exactly what I expected. I mean now opacity is working after my cursor move on the text. I wanted animation which will work right after I click on tag or element.

```js
/* add class 'active' to the clicked link */
event.preventDefault();
const clickedElement = this;
console.log('clickedElement:', clickedElement);
clickedElement.classList.add('active');
```

```css
.post {
  display: none;
  &.active {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: 3s;
  }
}

.post:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="posts">
  <article class="post active" id="article-1">
    <h3 class="post-title">Article 1</h3>
    <p class="post-author">by Marion Berry</p>
    <div class="post-content" <p>Duis non dolor efficitur erat int
      <p>
```

Comment: are you sure that you using CSS and not SASS? Nesting CSS would not be valid unless you would not sue CSS but SASS. Then you have an error in your HTML: `<div class="post-content" <p>Duis non ...` you dint finished the `<div>` opening tag and never closed it.

Answer (score 0):

That should do it? I added it as a toggle class so it can be turned on/off. You can change toggleClass to addClass if you don't want to be able to remove the class.

```js
$( ".post" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
});
```

```css
.post {   
  opacity:0.1;
}

.active {
  display: block; 
  opacity:0.2; 
  transition:3s;
}  

.post:hover {
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="post" id="article-1">
       <h3 class="post-title">Article 1</h3>
       <p class="post-author">by Marion Berry</p>
       <div class="post-content">
       <p>Duis non dolor efficitur erat int<p>
  </div>
  </article>
```

Comment: be aware that it is using jQuery not JS.